# BlockUI on Bootstrap Modal show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, blockui

I'm having issues showing blocking the whole modal content before it gets shown to the user with BlockUI.

If I simply initiate BlockUI after clicking the button that triggers the `modal`, it does loads, but the `loading message` does not get rendered correctly on the page, it's being placed at the top left corner.

```
$(document).on('click', '#modal-btn', function()
{
    mApp.block('#modal .modal-content',
    {
        overlayColor: '#000000',
        type: 'loader',
        state: 'success',
        message: 'Loading...'
    });
});
```

On the other hand, if I'm triggering the BlockUI only after the modal has been shown, then there's like a 500ms-1second when the user can edit the fields.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function()
{
    app.block('#modal .modal-content',
    {
        overlayColor: '#000000',
        type: 'loader',
        state: 'success',
        message: 'Loading...'
    });
});
```

Is there any way to either:

A) Center BlockUI's `loading` message using the first block of code?
B) Block the whole modal before it gets shown to the user somehow else, while everything (including the `loading text`) is being shown as it should do.